# How to get current product id from registry in controller without use objectmanager in magento2

Tags: magento2.2.3

```
use \Magento\Framework\Registry;
class Test extends Action
{ 
   protected $registry;

   public function __construct(
        Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

  public function execute()
   {
     $proid = $this->registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
   }

 }
```

> ->getId()` showing Error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null"

Comment: Can I Use Helper?

Comment: On which  you have tried

Comment: magento version 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

You can **a registry variable value** if  that **registry variable value  already set**.

In your code, at the controller, you have tried to fetch `current_product` variable value but on **this page the registry variable does not set yet**.
So, it is not possible to get that variable value.

A Magento registry like a PHP Global variable which can access ***through the current page, if that variable value already set at that page.***

Check out the blog how to use [Magento 2 Registry & Register](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-registry-register.html)

### EDIT

As you have submitted the  form and posting the data from the product page to your URL then  suggesting to send current product id as hidden input to this form So that you can  get the product id  to your custom action

Comment: I want Product Id from current product page in controller

Comment: are u talking about `current product page` means default magento product detail page?

Comment: yes, when i submit a form from product page then i want current product id in controller

Comment: Can You tell me another way for this?